# Change image's format name

Tags: javascript

There is if statement in which the format name of image should be changed.

For example in HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="image.webp"/>
```

Here only webp should be changed to jpg in every image with classname "image" using JavaScript

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: var imageName = imageName.replace('webp', 'jpg');

Comment: I have no idea how to get only the format name

Comment: Pass full name of image it will replace webp with jpg

Comment: @Bakhrom it’s not a format name. It is a file type, which is an attribute of a that particular element. Expressing the element that way, and expressing the (format) name as simply being a file type which is an attribute may help you.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Oh yes. Sorry. That is file type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `.attr`

```
$('.image').attr('src', function(_, attr) {
  return attr.replace('webp', 'jpg');
});
```

Comment: And what is the equivalent of attr.replace in native JS? Not jQuery.

Comment: @Bakhrom you've tagged your question with jquery - if you didn't want a jquery answer, then don't tag with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert any image extension to `jpg`.

```js
let obj = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

obj = Array.from(obj);

obj.forEach((val) => {

  let temp = val.src;
  temp = temp.split(".");
  temp[temp.length - 1] = "jpg";
  val.src = temp.join(".");
})


console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("image"));
```

```html
<img class="image" src="image.webp" />
<img class="image" src="image.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
 <h3>Convertidor 1.8</h3>

<input type="file" id="archivo" name="archivo" />
<select id="formatos">
    <option id="jpeg">.jpeg</option>
    <option id="png">.png</option>
    <option id="bmp">.bmp/.dib</option>
</select>
<br/>
<canvas style="width:50%;height:50%;" id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="descargar()">convertir</button>

<script>
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('archivo');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    var datosArchivo = "";

    function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            onReaderLoad(event);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        
    }
    var onReaderLoad = function (event) {
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function () {
            onImageLoad(image);
        }

        image.src = event.target.result;
        datosArchivo = image.src
        console.log(datosArchivo)
    }

    var onImageLoad = function (img) {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);        
    }

    function descargar(){
        var image = new Image();
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.download = image.name;
        var formatos = document.querySelector('#formatos');
        
        var selectedOption = formatos.options[formatos.selectedIndex];
        var selectedId = selectedOption.id;
        if(selectedId == "jpeg"){
            downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }
        if(selectedId == "png"){
            downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        }
        if(selectedId == "bmp"){
            downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/bmp');
        }        
        downloadLink.click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).